# Divide by zero error on PDF generation in DomPdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using DomPdf with Laravel (thujohn's package). I am unable to render a html page. I get the error:

> Division by Zero

Can somebody please guide how to solve it? Here's my code:

```
 $invoice_name  = rand(10000, 9999999) . '_' . time() . rand(100,99999). '.' . 'pdf';
 $pdf = new \Thujohn\Pdf\Pdf();
 $content = $pdf->load(View::make('FrontEnd.Pages.invoice', compact('order_pass')))->output();
 File::put(public_path('/invoice//'.$invoice_name), $content);
```

Comment: since there's no division (or math in general) occuring in any of that code, we can't help you.

Comment: When writing questions, if your code is heavily indented, please fix it for readers so that it is easier to read. I've done it for you, on this occasion. Thanks!

Comment: Can you let us have the stack trace where this error occurs? Have you done any debugging in the library you've mentioned?

Comment: @halfer I tried to debug, but $size is called from getBoundaries function.
Here's the image
http://i59.tinypic.com/or8ho2.png

Comment: If the error is generated by dompdf it would help to see the HTML stored in `$content`. Also, I don't think a "Division by Zero" error is fatal, so you might consider disabling reporting errors to the browser.

Comment: Are you using [this package](https://github.com/dobritz/thujohn-pdf-laravel)?